# Trigger to record changes to an employee

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a SQL Server trigger.

When I update the number of the department (`dept_no`) or the salary in the `Employees` table, it will insert a new entry into the `changes` table with the `EMP_NO`, the old and the new salary, the previous and the new department and the current date.

I tried this trigger code, but it is not working.

```
ALTER TRIGGER MODEMPLE
ON EMPLOYEES 
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @n_dept_no varchar(4),
            @n_salary money,
            @a_salary money,
            @emp_no int,
            @a_dept_no int

    SELECT @n_dept_no = dept_no FROM inserted
    SELECT @n_salary = salary FROM inserted

    SELECT @a_salary = SALARY FROM deleted
    SELECT @emp_no = EMP_NO FROM deleted
    SELECT @a_dept_no = DEPT_NO FROM deleted

    INSERT INTO CHANGES (EMP_NO, A_SALARY, N_SALARY, A_DEPT_NO, N_DEPT_NO, DATE) 
    VALUES (@emp_no, @a_salary, @n_salary, @a_dept_no, @n_dept_no, GETDATE())
END
```

Comment: Your trigger assumes no more than 1 row will ever be updated, an [all too common issue](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out how to improve it for updating more rows but I am not able

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of all the variables, they make no sense in this context because you need to handle multi-row updates. So just:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.MODEMPLE
ON dbo.EMPLOYEES FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT dbo.CHANGES
      (EMP_NO, A_SALARY, N_SALARY, A_DEPT_NO, N_DEPT_NO, DATE) 
       SELECT [old].EMP_NO,  
              [old].SALARY,  [new].salary,
              [old].DEPT_NO, [new].DEPT_NO, GETDATE()
       FROM       inserted AS [new] 
       INNER JOIN  deleted AS [old]
       ON [new].EMP_NO = [old].EMP_NO;
END
GO
```

You also may want to filter out rows where the update didn't make a material change (like `UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEES SET Salary += 0;`) but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: It appears invalid column names errors on the next columns A_SALARY,N_SALARY,A_DEPT_NO,N_DEPT_NO ( (They only appear on the select line- first query)

Comment: @b4tm4n What invalid columns? In the second example I added a fake column called `ver` in the event you want to track before and after versions of the row. In the first example I just used what I assumed would be matching column names that are in the `EMPLOYEES` table (and hence `inserted`) but I had to guess because you didn't post the table structure in the question. If you want to track that you'll have to add the appropriate column to `CHANGES`. If the `EMPLOYEES` table has a column called `DEPT_NO` and the `CHANGES` table it's called `A_DEPT_NO`, well, you'll have to adjust the statement.

Comment: @b4tm4n I think I understand now (check edit) but meaningless prefix like `A_SALARY` and `N_SALARY` certainly don't make it obvious.